# GetActiveTasks returns 0 for StorageReference

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I tried to upload a file on firebase cloud from MainActivity, i made when application is destoryed it start background services and make a file contains StorageReference.toString()
and in background service i used getReferenceFromUrl(string)
To complete the uploading and i used after it

```
List<UploadTask> tasks = storage.getActiveTasks();
```

and i used Toast.makeText(this, "tasks: " + tasks.size(), 0).show();

and it shows tasks = 0
Why? And the upload doesnt complete yet

MainActivity

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.ClipData;     
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;

import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public final int REQ_CD_IM = 101;

private Toolbar _toolbar;
private AppBarLayout _app_bar;
private CoordinatorLayout _coordinator;
private String image = "";
private UploadSaveed upload;
private String url = "";

private ImageView imageview1;
private Button button1;
private ProgressBar progressbar1;
private TextView textview1;

private AlertDialog.Builder d;
private Intent im = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(_savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    initialize(_savedInstanceState);
    upload = new UploadSaveed(getApplicationContext());

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 1000);
    } else {
        initializeLogic();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 1000) {
        initializeLogic();
    }
}

private void initialize(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
    _app_bar = findViewById(R.id._app_bar);
    _coordinator = findViewById(R.id._coordinator);
    _toolbar = findViewById(R.id._toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(_toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    _toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener((view) -> {
        onBackPressed();
    });
    imageview1 = findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
    button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    progressbar1 = findViewById(R.id.progressbar1);
    textview1 = findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    d = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    im.setType("*/*");
    im.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);

    imageview1.setOnClickListener((view) -> {
        startActivityForResult(im, REQ_CD_IM);
    });

    button1.setOnClickListener((view) -> {
        upload.setUploadListener(new UploadSaveed.UploadSavedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailureListener(Exception e) {
                SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), e.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressListener(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot task) {
                double progress = (100 * task.getBytesTransferred()) / task.getTotalByteCount();
                progressbar1.setProgress((int) progress);
                double bytes = task.getBytesTransferred();
                SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "transferred : " + bytes);
                if (upload.getUploadUrl() != null) {
                    url = upload.getUploadUrl();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPausedListener(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot task) {
                SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "your uploading was paused");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccessListener(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot task) {
                Task<Uri> taskk = task.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                while (!taskk.isSuccessful())
                    ;
                textview1.setText(taskk.getResult().toString());
                SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "finished");
            }
        });
        upload.UploadFile(image);
    });
}

private void initializeLogic() {
    if (!isMyServiceRunning(UploadService.class)) {
    } else {
        stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UploadService.class));
        stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UploadSaveed.class));
    }
    d.setTitle("AutoStart");
    d.setMessage("You must enable autostart for application to Work in background.");
    d.setPositiveButton("enable", (dialog, which) -> {
        try {
            final Intent intent = new Intent();
            String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER.toLowerCase();
            if ("xiaomi".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter",
                        "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
            } else if ("oppo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter",
                        "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));
                // intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.oppoguardelf",
                // "com.coloros.powermanager.fuelgaue.PowerConsumptionActivity"));
            } else if ("vivo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager",
                        "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
            } else if ("huawei".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager",
                        "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
            } else if ("Letv".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.letv.android.letvsafe",
                        "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity"));
            } else if ("Honor".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager",
                        "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
            } else {
                return;
            }
            startActivity(intent);
            SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(),
                    "please enable auto start to background application");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    d.setNegativeButton("I already enabled it", (dialog, which) -> {
    });
    d.create().show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int _requestCode, int _resultCode, Intent _data) {
    super.onActivityResult(_requestCode, _resultCode, _data);

    switch (_requestCode) {
    case REQ_CD_IM:
        if (_resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> _filePath = new ArrayList<>();
            if (_data != null) {
                if (_data.getClipData() != null) {
                    for (int _index = 0; _index < _data.getClipData().getItemCount(); _index++) {
                        ClipData.Item _item = _data.getClipData().getItemAt(_index);
                        _filePath.add(FileUtil.convertUriToFilePath(getApplicationContext(), _item.getUri()));
                    }
                } else {
                    _filePath.add(FileUtil.convertUriToFilePath(getApplicationContext(), _data.getData()));
                }
            }
            image = _filePath.get((int) (0));
        } else {

        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    try {
        File fi = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "saved");
        if (!fi.exists()) {
            fi.mkdirs();
        }
        File gpxfile = new File(fi, "saved.txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writer.append(url);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException ee) {
        ee.printStackTrace();
    }
    upload.PauseUploading();
    startService(new Intent(this, UploadService.class));
    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UploadSaveed.class));
}

private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
                }
            }
        return false;
    }
}
```

UploadService

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class UploadService extends Service {

public static final String TAG = "UploadService";

private UploadSaveed upload;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent i, int flags, int startId) {
    upload = new UploadSaveed(getApplicationContext());
    upload.setUploadListener(new UploadSaveed.UploadSavedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailureListener(Exception e) {
            simpleNotifaction(1, "Upload Faild", "Upload Faild !");
            try {
                File fi = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "saved");
                if (!fi.exists()) {
                    fi.mkdirs();
                }
                File gpxfile = new File(fi, "errors.txt");
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
                writer.append(e.toString());
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException ee) {
                ee.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressListener(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot task) {
            double progress = (100 * task.getBytesTransferred()) / task.getTotalByteCount();
            notiProgress(1, "Uploading", "Your file is Uploading..", progress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPausedListener(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot task) {
            SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "your uploading is paused");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccessListener(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot task) {
            Task<Uri> taskk = task.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
            while (!taskk.isSuccessful())
                ;
            simpleNotifaction(1, "Uploaded", "Url: " + taskk.getResult().toString());
            stopSelf();
        }
    });
    upload.UploadFormUrl(upload.getUploadUrl2());

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent i) {
    startService(new Intent(this, UploadService.class));
    super.onTaskRemoved(i);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
}

private void notiProgress(final double _id, final String _title, final String _text, final double _progress) {
    final Context context = getApplicationContext();

    android.app.NotificationManager notificationManager = (android.app.NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    int notificationId = (int) _id;
    String channelId = "channel-01";
    String channelName = "Channel Name";
    int importance = android.app.NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        android.app.NotificationChannel mChannel = new android.app.NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName,
                importance);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }

    androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context, channelId).setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_upload).setTicker("")
                    .setContentTitle(_title).setContentText(_text).setProgress((int) 100, (int) _progress, false);

    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
}

private void simpleNotifaction(int id2, String title, String description) {
    androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(this,
            "channel-01")
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_upload_done)
                    .setSound(android.media.RingtoneManager
                            .getDefaultUri(android.media.RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setContentTitle(title).setContentText(description)
                    .setPriority(androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX).setAutoCancel(true);

    androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat
            .from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(id2, builder.build());
    }
}
```

UploadSaveed

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.Intent;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class UploadSaveed extends Service {

public static final String TAG = "UploadSaveed";

private FirebaseApp app;
private StorageReference storagee, path;
private UploadTask path2;
private List<UploadTask> tasks;
private String urll;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent i, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

public interface UploadSavedListener {
    void onProgressListener(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot task);

    void onFailureListener(@NonNull Exception e);

    void onSuccessListener(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot task);

    void onPausedListener(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot task);
}

private UploadSavedListener listener;

public void setUploadListener(UploadSavedListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

public UploadSaveed() {
}

public UploadSaveed(Context c) {
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApplicationId("1:982483603219:android:ce7ef5f660652cdca054e6")
            .setApiKey("AIzaSyAhffAnCI7dG0d3NucUAjPM6oWaX6mVSHk")
            .setDatabaseUrl("trav-chat-2-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com").setStorageBucket("trav-chat-2.appspot.com")
            .build();
    try {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(c, options, "firebasedb");
        app = FirebaseApp.getInstance("firebasedb");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(c, options);
        app = FirebaseApp.getInstance("firebasedb");
    }
    try {
        File fi = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "saved");
        if (!fi.exists()) {
            fi.mkdirs();
        }
        File gpxfile = new File(fi, "ssaved.txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writer.append(app.toString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException ee) {
        ee.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void UploadFile(String file) {
    Uri file2 = Uri.parse(file);
    Uri file3 = Uri.fromFile(new File(file));
    storagee = FirebaseStorage.getInstance(app).getReference();
    path = storagee.child("test image").child(file2.getLastPathSegment());
    path2 = path.putFile(file3);
    if (listener != null) {
        path2.addOnFailureListener((e) -> {
            listener.onFailureListener(e);
        }).addOnPausedListener((task) -> {
            listener.onPausedListener(task);
        }).addOnProgressListener((task) -> {
            listener.onProgressListener(task);
        }).addOnSuccessListener((task) -> {
            listener.onSuccessListener(task);
        });
    } else if (listener == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("listener cannot be null");
    }
}

/*
public void UploadFormUrl(String url) {
    storagee = FirebaseStorage.getInstance(app).getReferenceFromUrl(url);
    tasks = storagee.getActiveUploadTasks();
    if (tasks.size() > 0) {
        if (listener != null) {
            path2 = tasks.get(0);
            ResumeUploading();
            SketchwareUtil.showMessage(this, "lol");
            path2.addOnFailureListener((e) -> {
                listener.onFailureListener(e);
            }).addOnPausedListener((task) -> {
                listener.onPausedListener(task);
            }).addOnProgressListener((task) -> {
                listener.onProgressListener(task);
            }).addOnSuccessListener((task) -> {
                listener.onSuccessListener(task);
            });
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("listener cannot be null");
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("tasks cannot be equal 0 or less");
    }
}
*/

public String getUploadUrl() {
    if (path != null) {
        return path.toString();
    } else if (storagee != null) {
        return storagee.toString();
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Storage Reference is null");
    }
}

public void CancelUploading() {
    path2.cancel();
}

public void PauseUploading() {
    path2.pause();
}

public void ResumeUploading() {
    path2.resume();
}

public String getUploadUrl2() {
    urll = FileUtil.readFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/saved/saved.txt");
    return urll;
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent i) {
    startService(new Intent(this, UploadSaveed.class));
    super.onTaskRemoved(i);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **intent**
Try this code:

```
val intent = Intent(this, Main2Activity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```